# storing text in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, formatting

I'm using mongo to store website contents, including some pretty long chunks of text, but I'm having this weird issue with formatting. When I have a long string, it won't wrap or break or scroll, no matter what I do to the container. Is this an obvious issue with mongodb and I should try something else, or is it just something to do with the way I'm using it?

**edit**

It's basically a mini-blog. I'm displaying an image with a related paragraph in a box tied to each database entry, so users can scroll through them. App is in node.js on Heroku, view engine is jade, database is MongoHQ via monk.

route for 'feed' page in index.js:

```
exports.feed = function(db) {
    return function(req, res) {
        var collection = db.get('contents');
        collection.find({},{sort:{date:1}}, function(e,docs){
            res.render('feed', {
                "feed": docs
            });
        });
    };
};
```

and on the page itself:

```
each pages, i in feed
    a(href="/cont/#{pages.href}" title="#{pages.title}")
        .feedbox
            .feedimg(style="background-image: url(#{pages.img})")
            .feedtext
                p #{pages.text}
```

Comment: Give an example of the data you are trying to store, and explain how you are trying to present it.

Comment: In order to help, you need to provide code and steps to reproduce. It's highly likely you have an issue on the client, not the database.

Comment: Edited to update. Let me know if anything pops out or more info is needed. Thanks so much for the replies.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is just a database. As such, its purpose is not to mess with the data you're trying to store in it. 
Your problem is most likely related to the way you output your data, and has nothing to do with mongodb itself.

Comment: I hoped that was the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was just CSS- where I used "white-space: normal;", I had a typo. Yikes.